# ODATA and CRUD operations with MVC Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, web, odata

I need to create a service (currently with ASP.NET Web Api) that is taking data from SQL database and exposes them using OData protocol. I'm extremely new to OData and Web Api.

The problem is I don't know how to perform crud operations - I've looked through some samples available online but my case is a little bit more complicated (or maybe not, hard to say). I'm using Entity Framework.

Sometimes I need to do the "GET" with querying table directly but do "POST" with stored procedure. The biggest problem i have is limitation in parameters amount. As I understand I can have only one.

This is rather an issue in my case:

```
public class ProjectsController : ODataController
{
    [EnableQuery]
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public IQueryable<GetProjects_Result> Get(string key)
    {
        var context = new OPMLVSQL001Entities();
        IQueryable<GetProjects_Result> results = context.GetProjects(key);
        return results;
    }

    [EnableQuery]
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public GetProject_Result Get(int projectId, string loginName)
    {
        var context = new OPMLVSQL001Entities();
        GetProject_Result result = context.GetProject(projectId, loginName).FirstOrDefault();
        return result;
    }
```

that code won't work - just to get all projects, I need to pass a login parameter. To get one entity, I need to use different method - and I have to pass two parameters. Which I don't know how to do in OData (I thought of a hack - passing json table in the only parameter I can use).

So is there a way to use more than one parameter?

I also have to implement a "create" method - an entity is being created with stored procedure again. What is the best way to follow in this case?

One way probably is to add, Project entity to the project and do post like this:

```
    [EnableQuery]
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(Project project)
    {
    }
```

but what if I have some logic in `dbo.CreateProject([bunch of parameters])` that I need to run along and for that reason I'd like to run the stored procedure. Use values from projects to initialize `dbo.CreateProjects` parameters? I really don't know what's the best way to follow.

Comment: In https://github.com/OData/WebApi/tree/master/OData/test, there are many test cases that you can find about the CRUD operation with OData. Besides, you can use attribute routing for composite keys, and the function/action also supports multiple parameters. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean saying that you want to pass more than one parameter? `OData` definitely support complex queries with multiple filter parameters and [much more](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/odata-v4.0-part2-url-conventions.html).

While making queries, `OData` allows you to define how exactly data should be retrieved, filtered and projected. You can use any number of parameters when filtering. For example, the following query string:

```
/people?$skip=10&$top=5&$select=FirstName, LastName&$filter=Address eq 'Redmond'
```

will be translated to something like

```
queryable
    .Where(p => p.Address == "Redmond")
    .Skip(10)
    .Take(5)
    .Select(p => new { p.FirstName, p.LastName });
```

Assuming that you are using Entity Framework, this query will be further translated into `SQL` database query.

Comment: In EntityFramework you can also get data through running stored procedures/functions. Let's say, that to get data with stored procedures i need to call it by passing two parameters. dbo.GetDriver(@IDDriver, @IDLoginName). And i want to make that call inside "Get" method. It would like that:
public IQueryable<GetDriverByLoginName_Result> Get(string login, int id)
        {
            var context = new DatabaseContextEntities();
            return context.GetDriverByLoginName(id, key);
        }
What is the best way to make such scenario work?

Comment: @skyrunner you don't need `OData` for this scenario. Just call your Web API method like this: `/api/drivers/{id}?login={login}`.